# How does swift know which files to import?

Tags: ios, swift, import

I'm diving into swift from the land of Objective-C, and I'm curious about swift's importing functionality. I've discovered that there's no need to import my own classes, like so:

Objective-C:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomObject.h"

CustomObject* newObject = ...
```

Swift:

```
import UIKit
//no need to import CustomObject

var newObject: CustomObject...
```

My question is, how does swift accomplish this? Where does it look for .swift files to automatically import? Is it just any .swift file that's added to your project's target? I don't want to just handwave this and then get caught by surprise later when something doesn't import like magic!

Comment: swift will be open by public by end of this year, so stay tuned to find out :).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm going to explain this with grace but here it goes...

Let's say you're creating an app called `Battlefront`. When you're adding files/classes to your application, they are in fact added to your app's module, the `Battlefront` module. Let's say you created a class called `Hero`, well, your class is not only `Hero`, it is `Battlefront.Hero` but since you're using it in the context of the `Battlefront` module, there is no need to specify the module name when using your class.

Imports in Swift works mostly with modules. I suppose you could import a single class in Swift but I haven't tried it so I can't comment on this. Let's say you're importing `CoreData`, well you're importing the whole module by using `import CoreData`.

By default, classes are using the `internal` access control. If you wanted to expose classes inside `Battlefront` to be available to other modules, you'd have to specify your class as public:

```
// Default is internal, not available outside Battlefront
class Hero {

}

// Public class, is available outside Battlefront
public class Weapon {

}
```

You can read more on Access Control [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3).
I suppose you could simplify the relationship to `Target` equals a `Module` but that would be taking a shortcut. Could be a start of understanding the concept though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, Xcode accesses all .swift files in your project.